# Long range interface between a Raspberry Pi and a smartphone?

Tags: wifi, hardware, wireless

I would like to control a **Raspberry Pi 4** with my smartphone (for my drone). Now I'm looking for an interface between the RPi and my Android phone.

**Requirements**:

- Control with a web interface or app
- Range: at least **1 km (0.62 miles)**.
- Data rate: I don't need a high data rate because I don't want a camera live stream. I only want to send small commands, like forward, backward, ...
- Fast connection -> max. 0.5 second: Phone -> RPi
- No license (for special frequencies)
- One-time purchase -> No monthly fees

Here are some that I have looked at, but do not meet my requirements:

**1) Use a sim card for the RPi:**

- Websocket connection over a server -> web interface
- Unlimited range
- **Monthly fees**

**2) Use the RPi as Access Point**

- Connect the phone with the RPi-Wifi -> web interface
- **I think: too little range**

**3) Connect my phone with a self-built antenna e.g. with RFM95W**

- Connect the antenna with USB-C to my phone
- App
- **I must program a driver**

**4) Bluetooth**

- **Too little range**

Thanks for your Hardware Recommendations!

Comment: Your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm not the only person who has this question.

Comment: Maybe, but the format isn't made for this kind of questions. How many answers do you expect to get? Do you expect that you will find one who is willing to make a complete project description that explains all your requirements and offer you the solution in one answer? I don't believe it. And no, comments are not made for discussion. After some comments you will get an automated request to use the chat. You may have a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: The project is already finished. But at the time the drone and the remote control have an arduino, these communicating with the RFM95W. Now I want to upgrade to a smartphone control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I opted for this solution:

Android Phone > **Serial** > Self built antenna with an Arduino > **RFM95W** > Raspberry Pi

- 2km range
- Cheap
- Fast
- Easy

Links:

[Android Serial](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart)

[RFM95W](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3072)

Comment: Hi did you put the antenna on the drone or on the smartphone?

Comment: Both the drone and the smartphone have an antenna, otherwise, they could not communicate.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer
So the rfm95w is both on the drone and the phone? How did you connect it on the phone since it is industrial?

Comment: USB C (Phone) to Micro USB (Arduino)

Comment: OK thank you and on the drone, how was it connected?

Comment: Directly using the GPIO pins. See this image: https://www.digikey.ee/maker-media/7af271bf-3f0a-4a7e-a66b-dab5b85f3b4c

Comment: Thanks so in this configuration,the drone does not conect to anything except to your phone (or better said: the phone connects to the drone)?

Comment: Exactly! My phone is basically the remote control for my drone.